# Need floating IPs to create a container in IBM Bluemix (BXNUI0110E)

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

In the Bluemix console, when I try to create a container, I get this error:

> BXNUI0110E: Could not allocate IBM Containers resources. Insufficient
>   ORG quota to allocate to new SPACE. Cannot exceed your organization
>   '<my org>' floating IPs. Use IBM Bluemix Manage Organizations to
>   adjust quota allocation.

The containers summary says my org is using "0/2 Public IPs," so it seems like the new container should use one of those available IPs. In Manage Organizations, I've used the Horizon browser to allocate a couple of floating IPs, but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Bluemix trial account, you can only create containers in a single space, the one you created your first container in. You get this error when you try to create a container in any other space. To avoid the error, switch back to the space you created your first container in and you'll be able to create more containers there.

In a Bluemix paid account, you can create containers in all your org's spaces.

For more info, see "[BXNUI0110E: Could not allocate IBM Containers resources](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/204090/bxnui0110e-could-not-allocate-ibm-containers-resou.html)."